# Python Tkinter changing line width

Tags: python, tkinter

```
if self.m[w] == 'Prelim_value':
        self.DrawArea2.create_line((x, 150-self.rmm2200[w]),(x + self.zoom, 150-self.rmm2200[w+1]), fill = "red", width=2)
else:
        self.DrawArea.create_line((x, 150-self.rmm2200[w]),(x + self.zoom, 150-self.rmm2200[w+1]), fill = "red", width=1)
```

The above doesn't work as planned.  If the value in the datafile is a Prelim value I want the line to be 2 pixels wide to show that it is prelim data.  It the data is finalized data I want it to only be one pixel wide.  Everything comes across as one pixel wide.  The last 10 lines of data are all prelim values and are marked as such.  How do I get this to work correctly.

Yes, I'm shortcutting everything as I don't have much time to work online.  The program works fine other than this and not being able to figure out my other recently posted question on PgUp and PgDn detection.

Comment: Could you place a `print(self.m[w], type(self.m[w]))` right above your `if`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the color of one of those lines -- that will make it easy to see which line of code is being executed. Most likely, your `if` statement is failing for every line. Or, put a print statement in each block (the if, and else), to verify that the values are exactly what you think they are.